# no such module UITintedButton

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Recently I do a project about iOS development, I cloned the project from github and got a problem with "no such module UITintedButton"

[image]

Here is the screenshot of my output after I execute command "pod install"

[image]

I think UITintedButton has been installed. But in my project, the pod.framework is still red.

[image]

Did I install cocoapods successfully?

Comment: what does your Podfile look like?

Comment: xcodeproj 'Atlas.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'HanekeSwift'
pod 'UITintedButton'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure after you have installed your cocoapods that you open the  xcworkspace not the xcproject in xcode.